# SQL - Is there a way to write nested Case statement with multiple conditions and return multiple values within the same column?

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I have two cases set up in my query and the one that I am struggling with is the second one. The issue is that in the second case statement, once the first condition is met it doesn't evaluate the following conditions if one of them is met. Is it possible to evaluate all conditions and return them in a single column and what is the best way to go about doing this without having to write multiple nested case statements?

Currently, case statement 1 returns a value if all conditions are met. Case statement 2 returns which conditions it fails but stops at the condition it fails first. For example: if value does not equal to condition1, condition4, and condition5 it returns only "failed condition1" based on my case statement but I would like it to return "failed condition1, condition4, and condition5".

**Actual Result**: failed condition1

**Desired Result**: failed condition1, condition4,condition5

Is there a way to do this? I only used 5 conditions in my example, which may not seem like much, but in my actual query I have more than 10+ conditions. If it matters, I am querying out of Teradata.

Here is what I have currently:

```
SELECT
ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
CASE --CASE STATEMENT 1
  WHEN value = condition1
     AND value = condition2
     AND value = condition3
     AND value = condition4
     AND value = condition5
    THEN 'ELIGIBLE'
  ELSE 'NOT ELIGIBLE' 
END AS IS_ELIGIBLE,
CASE --CASE STATEMENT 2
  WHEN IS_ELIGIBLE = 'NOT ELIGIBLE' THEN
    CASE 
      WHEN value <> condition1 THEN 'failed condition1'
      WHEN value <> condition2 THEN 'failed condition2'
      WHEN value <> condition3 THEN 'failed condition3'
      WHEN value <> condition4 THEN 'failed condition4'
      WHEN value <> condition5 THEN 'failed condition5'
    END
END AS NOT_ELIGIBLE_REASON

FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
```

Comment: Your inner CASE could be something like `TRIM(TRAILING(',' FROM 'failed'||CASE WHEN value <> condition1 THEN  ' condition1,' ELSE '' END||CASE ... END)`